# VSCode - C++ code runner doesn't work correctly when code-runner.runInTerminal is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

C++ Code Runner in VS Code doesn't seem to be able to build the executable correctly if the "run in terminal" option is set to be true - `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`.

By default, the output window is read-only, so if my C++ program has no user input via `cin`, the code runner is able to build the `foo.exe` correctly from a `foo.cpp` file. However, if I add the above configuration to the `settings.json` file (to enable user-input, more details [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-compile-your-c-code-in-visual-studio-code/)), it appears that the `.exe` executable is not built.

This is the sample code I used -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  cout<< "Hello World" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output -

**Successful Execution**

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Manish\Documents\Development\Github\HackerRank\C++\" && g++ 1.cpp -o 1 && "c:\Users\Manish\Documents\Development\Github\HackerRank\C++\"1
Hello World

[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.235 seconds
```

**Unsuccessful Execution (same file)** -

```
Manish@manish-lenovo MINGW64 ~/Documents/Development/Github/HackerRank/C++ (master)
$ cd "c:\Users\Manish\Documents\Development\Github\HackerRank\C++\" && g++ 1.cpp -o 1 && "c:\Users\Manish\Documents\Development\Github\HackerRank\C++\"1      
bash: cd: c:\Users\Manish\Documents\Development\Github\HackerRank\C++" && g++ 1.cpp -o 1 && c:UsersManishDocumentsDevelopmentGithubHackerRankC++"1: No such file or directory
```

Screenshots (if required) -

[image: err4]

[image: err3]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The Bash shell which is used to run the program in the second case uses backslash as an escape introducer, much like backslash is used in C++.

In your configuration files you need to use either forward slash as path delimiter, or use double backward slash to escape it.